# Should answers be discouraged on rule-breaking questions?

Tags: discussion, answers

I just came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36955992/python-function-cant-answer?noredirect=1).

The question itself has already been put on hold, as the OP has not included a minimal, verifiable example, doesn't refer to a specific issue, and is pretty blatantly asking the community to write their code for them (by the looks of it, it's for a homework assignment, to boot).

There's an answer to this question, and (roughly) the same answer appears in the comments; is this kind of contribution useful on SO, or should answers on such questions be actively discouraged?

Comment: I voted to delete that question. Getting answers deleted along the question should be discouraging enough (especially if rep was earned from that answer).

Comment: Good point; I didn't know that rep earned from an answer on a deleted question was revoked from the answerer.

Comment: Strange that the person that supplied an answer also apparently voted "unclear what you are asking".